# Phase and group velocity of wave

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line, physics, waveguide

When an electromagnetic wave enter the waveguide, what is the change in the phase and group velocity that happen in waveguide?

Does wavelength or frequency of wave change when it enter the wave guide?

Answer (score 3):

The frequency cannot change.

What happens to the speed and wavelength depends on what sort of waveguide it is.

If it's a TEM waveguide, like coax or microstrip, then the phase and group velocity fall, and the wavelength reduces.

If it's a TE or TM waveguide, a metal tube with space in the middle, what we would conventionally call a 'waveguide', then the group velocity falls, but the phase velocity increases, increasing the wavelength.

At the waveguide cutoff frequency, phase velocity becomes infinite, and group velocity falls to zero.

Comment: The wavelength cannot increase above what it is for free space. In the waveguide \$\dfrac{1}{\lambda_{WG}} - \dfrac{1}{\lambda_{FS}} = \dfrac{1}{4a^2}\$ so if the wavelength got bigger the waveguide dimensions would (strangely and awkwardly) become negative. [See this](http://iitd.vlab.co.in/?sub=65&brch=180&sim=294&cnt=1)

Comment: @Andyaka what's your source for that equation? You've got me looking for my Ramo Winnery & VanDuzer in the loft now! You'll agree that phase velocity increases, I thought it was phase velocity rather than group velocity that controlled the wavelength? You will agree that as the frequency drops to the cutoff frequency, the whole guide resonates in unison, looking like a very large velocity and a very large wavelength.

Comment: I think you might be referring to "guide wavelength". I remember the formula I quoted so I went hunting... It's linked as a paper at the end of my prev comment but it's not a solid derivation; just an experiment that quotes it.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, I'm referring to 'guide wavelength'. I've not yet found my RWvD, but Duffin confirms that \$\lambda_g\$ increases above that of free space (Advanced Electricity and Magnetism, 1968, p207, eqns 10.20 to 10.24)

Comment: http://www.hep.manchester.ac.uk/u/rmj/Third_Year_Lab/microwaves.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjxwanOuNDaAhUKq48KHUiZDCcQFjAIegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw3YLHsRRQdI-cf7-98iQ4JP --- wavelength should always increase inside waveguide it says.

Comment: @MeenieLeis try again with that link and note that the guide wavelength (a somewhat arbitrary facet of a waveguide) increases but the signal wavelength must get smaller. However, it is fairly unclear what the question is referring to. Many thanks for the down vote to whom it may concern.

Comment: @Andyaka Guide wavelength is not arbitrary, it's the physical distance between successive peaks of the electric field, at any snapshot in time. With this definition, guide wavelength is reduced in TEM guides, and increased in TE and TM guides, compared to free space wavelength measured by the same definition. This means that phase velocity, frequency*wavelength, is always faster than the speed of light in hollow waveguides.  There is no 'signal' wavelength, but note that group velocity, the information content of the signal, reassuringly is slower than the speed of light.

Answer (score 0):

In space or air, the speed of an EM wave is determined by \$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon_0\cdot\mu_0}}\$.

In a medium where the relative permittivity is different (\$\epsilon_0\cdot\epsilon_r\$) to that of free space (\$\epsilon_0\$) the speed will reduce and the wavelength will shorten because frequency cannot alter.

Comment: Are you *sure* the wavelength will shorten? It does in coax.

Comment: @Neil_UK got me thinking then.... F = \$\dfrac{v}{\lambda}\$ so if v reduces then so does wavelength!

Comment: It's possibly the oddity of guide wavelength being greater than that of free space that prompted the OP's question. It certainly troubled me initially when I was an undergrad. At least group velocity does the right thing and slows down.

Comment: Yeah guide wavelength is just something that could equally be expressed as an angle and would make more sense to most folk.